# Clearbox Radius attributes through SQL statement?

Tags: sql, radius

I authenticate users through Radius, and I have the option to assign Radius attributes through SQL statements, but I can't for the life of me find any documentation on this. Anyone know the proper syntax?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, I figured it out, and for anyone else who ends up having this problem:

Under the Authorization tab, in the Response List:
When adding an attribute from an SQL query, the first selected variable from the query is the attribute and the second is the value.

ex.

`SELECT 'attribute', value FROM table WHERE username ='$u'`

For a more specific example:

`SELECT 'Ascend-Data-Rate', hsbrate.rate FROM hsbrate, customer WHERE  customer.id = hsbrate.id AND username='$u'`

This statement will basically pass the following:
Ascend-Data-Rate=1024000

(assuming 1024000 is the rate value stored in the database)

NOTE: $u is an understood variable in Clearbox Radius that denotes the current-active user being authenticated.

Answer (score 0):

kylex, try these links and see if they help. Specifically the first one

http://www.xperiencetech.com/forum/topic.asp?TOPIC_ID=97

http://www.xperiencetech.com/forum/topic.asp?TOPIC_ID=62